# Add PHP variables together from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, foreach

I have some php variables in a while loop which collect data from columns in a table per product id but the results for "care0,care3,care5" only respond to the first id added - there is no cumulative addition for subsequent product id's for the variables mentioned.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","database");
global $con;
$ip = getIp();
$sel_price = "select * from products where ip_address='$ip'";
$run_price = mysqli_query($con, $sel_price);
while ($p_price=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_price)){
    $pro_id = $p_price['product_id'];
    $pro_price = "select * from products where product_id='$pro_id'";
    $run_pro_price = mysqli_query($con, $pro_price);
    while ($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_pro_price)){
        $product_id = $pp_price['product_id'];
        $product_type = $pp_price['product_type'];
        $product_category = $pp_price['product_category'];
        $product_brand = $pp_price['product_brand'];
        $product_model = $pp_price['product_model'];
        $product_price = array($pp_price['product_price']);
        $product_install = $pp_price['product_install'];
        $product_delivery = '20.00';
        $product_recycle = '15.00';
        //Problem Starts Here
        $care0 = '0.00';
        $care3 = $pp_price['care3'];
        $care5 = $pp_price['care5'];
        //Problem ends here
        $product_title = $pp_price['product_title'];
        $product_image = $pp_price['product_imagelist'];
        $single_price = $pp_price['product_price'];
        $values = array_sum($product_price);
        $subtotal += $values;
        $fulltotal = $subtotal+$product_delivery+$product_install+$product_recycle;
?>
```

The result of the variables is being echoed in the values of 3 radio buttons and is updated on submission of the form, the amount is then echoed in a adjacent div.

```
<html>
<div class="bask-tot3"><p class="nobr"><span class="grey-lite">Extended Warranty&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="blue-link"><a href="warranty" title="find out about extended warranties...">find out more</a></span><br/><br/></span></p>
<p class="nobr"><input type="radio" name="care" value="<?php echo $care0; ?>" checked="checked" />&nbsp;No thanks</p>
<p class="nobr"><input type="radio" name="care" value="<?php echo $care3; ?>" />&nbsp;3 years</p>
<p class="nobr"><input type="radio" name="care" value="<?php echo $care5; ?>" />&nbsp;5 years</p>
</div>
<div class="bask-tot4"><p><?php echo £ . $_POST["care"]; ?></p></div>
</html>
```

As you can see, care3 and care5 are coming from the table data but care0 is not.

The calculator for the price of multiple products $product_price works fine because it is in an array but the calculator for the price of multiple care packages only responds to the first item added. I think I'm missing a foreach statement, or need to make these 3 variables into an array but I'm at a loss on how to implement this.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Some idea of where those while loops are actually closed would also be good

Comment: Apologies. The while loop is closed after the echo for $single_price which corresponds to each individual product added. This is purely to stack products on top of each other. The problem I have is contained in the same loop.

Comment: I think there's only one hint you need: `$product[] = array($product_id, $product_type, ...)` - _but_ you got everything in `$pp_price` already, so just do `$product[]=$pp_price;` (you'll need to define `$product = array();` before the while though)

Comment: Jeff, I tried your suggestion but values are still only being represented for 1 product, not multiples.